# Solar System Project, C++. Can't get negative accelerations(planet won't loop back around)

Tags: c++, model, simulation, physics, orbital-mechanics

First, I'm using something very close to euler's method to calculate my planet's positions. I know this is not the most accurate method, but I've been working on using velocity verlet for close to a week now and cannot get it to work. My problem is I can't get my planet to loop back around the sun, the x or y positions are constantly increasing. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
Here's my code:

```
void updatePosition(CelestialObject object1, CelestialObject object2 )

{ // -----------------------------X calculations-----------------------------------
    //calc force
    float forceX = forceFuncX(object1.getX(), object2.getX(),object1.getY(), object2.getY(), object1.getMass(), object2.getMass());`

    //accel calc
    float AX = accelerationFuncX(forceX,object1.getX(), object2.getX(),object1.getMass());
    agk::PrintC("Accel X: "); 
    float AXprint = AX*dt;
    agk::Print(AXprint);

    //velocity
    float VX  = object1.getVX();
    VX = VX + AX*dt;
    agk::PrintC("Velocity X: ");
    agk::Print(VX);

    //positionCalc
    float X = object1.getX();
    X = X + VX*dt;
    agk::PrintC("Position X: ");
    agk::Print(X);

    //-------------------------Y calculations------------------------------------
    //force
    float forceY = forceFuncY(object1.getX(), object2.getX(),object1.getY(), object2.getY(), object1.getMass(), object2.getMass());

    //accel
    float AY = accelerationFuncY(forceY,object1.getY(),object2.getY(), object1.getMass()); //y
    agk::PrintC("Accel Y: ");
    float AYprint = AY*dt;
    agk::Print(AYprint);

    //velocity
    float VY = object1.getVY();
    VY = VY + AY*dt;
    agk::PrintC("Velocity Y: ");
    agk::Print(VY);

    //position
    float Y = object1.getY();
    Y = Y + VY*dt;
    agk::PrintC("Position Y: ");
    agk::Print(Y);

    object1.setPosition(X, Y);
    agk::CreateParticles(X,Y);
}
```

Here's the functions it calls:

```
double forceFuncX(float object1x,float object2x,float object1y, float object2y, double mass1, double mass2)
{
    float d = object1x - object2x;
    float r = sqrt(pow(object2x - object1x,2) + pow(object2y-object1y,2));;
    //float r = sqrt(pow(object1x-object2x,2)+pow(object1y-object2y,2));
    //double F = (G*(mass1*mass2))/pow(d,2);
    float F = (G*(mass1*mass2))/(r*r);

    return F;
}


double forceFuncY(float object1x,float object2x,float object1y, float object2y, double mass1, double mass2)
{
    float d = object1y - object2y;
    float r = sqrt(pow(object2x - object1x,2) + pow(object2y-object1y,2));;
    //float r = sqrt(pow(object1x-object2x,2)+pow(object1y-object2y,2));
    //double F = (G*(mass1*mass2))/pow(d,2);
    float F = (G*(mass1*mass2))/(r*r);

    return F;
}
```

and

```
float accelerationFuncX(float force, float object1x, float object2x, double mass) //gives the acceleration of an object
{
    float accel = (force*(object2x-object1x))/mass;
    return accel;
}

float accelerationFuncY(float force, float object1y, float object2y, double mass)
{
    float accel =(force*(object2y-object1y))/mass;
    return accel;
}
```

Comment: Not reading the code in detail - assuming your functions are correct - I fear floating point errors will throw your planet out of orbit.

Comment: Can you also provide a minimal version of the `CelestialObject` class and a very simple driver?  It's not clear, for example, whether you are assuming initial velocities of zero or not.  Also, velocities are calculated, but don't seem to update their corresponding `CelestialObject`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Thank you for noticing I didn't update the velocities. Anyway, hopefully this is some of the information you want for `CelestialObject`

`CelestialObject(int index, string filename,float pX, float pY, float VX, float VY, float AX, float AY, double mass);` my constructor 

and 
`CelestialObject earth(EARTH_INDEX,"abdSolarSystem/earth.png", 1000, 1000, 0,200,0,0,1000);`

Comment: Are your acceleration functions correct?  Given F = m * a; and a = F/m, where does the distance between the two objects come into the equation?

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org) would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a cartesian coordinate system, you should find that your force along x is in some configurations positive, and in some others, negative, and same along y. In particular, the force F is a vector that points away from the center of mass of a planet, towards the center of mass of the sun it orbits around. So there are two problems with the code:

1. You return Fy and Fx, both are always positive and are equal to the gravitational force between the two bodies: F=G * m1 * m2/r^2. But F is the length of the force vector. The Fx and Fy components of the force vector would then be something like Fx = - F cos alpha and Fy = - F sin alpha, where alpha is the angle of planet relative to x axis. For example, if alpha=0, and sun is at center of your coordinate system (x=y=0), then Fx = -F (because the planet is at positive x and sun at x=0 hence the force points to negative x).
2. The acceleration a is F/m, whereas you have vec F*(delta x) / m, where vec F is the force *vector* and delta x is x distance between the planet and sun. The a is in the same direction as force vector. So you should have something like ax = Fx/m1 and ay=Fy/m1 if you want to compute acceleration of m1 mass (say, the planet).

Fixing your code based on the above should be straightforward so I will leave it up to you to do, but if not clear just post comment.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the angle and converting it forward and backward with trigonometric functions, use the vector force

> F=(Fx, Fy)=-(x,y)*G * m1 * m2/r^3.

Also, use the tutorial ["Moving Stars Around"](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/v1_web.html) for reference implementation of various symplectic and not-so-symplectic integration methods and the paper by [Hairer-etal.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.7106) for the theory and history behind it.